# Powerbi data refresh issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I receive weekly data set from our suppliers regarding the future stay of accomodation.
I have created few macros to do the data modification. So everytime I receive the email from our suppliers, I run the macros to make the modifications and then copy paste the modified data into the source sheet which I have used to create the powerbi dashboard.

In this dashboard I have created a column called "outstanding nights" which is the difference betweeen today's date and departure date. Suppose the departure date is october 2nd, the outstanding night for today will be -8(as today's date is oct 10th). If the departure date is october 11th, then the outstanding night should be 1(as today's date is oct 10th).

This outstanding night column is being updated in my powerbi desktop version. But on publishing this on my workspace>powerbi service , I do not see this column updating based on today's date.

Suppose the departure date is october 2nd, the outstanding night for tomorrow will be still -8(even though tomorrow's date is oct 11th).

My data source is in my local desktop folder. I need to find a way for this column to be updated even on powerbi service after publishing it from the desktop (I publish from desktop to powerbi service every monday but I want the outstanding night column to be updated based on today's date)

Could someone please help me with this issue?